# MySQL and SQL inserting data into JavaScript variable!

Tags: javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin, google-maps

I have a javascript file that has the variable named locations, with some data in quotes for example, 'name', '123 lane', and etc.  I want the variable to get data from a database and not the plain text. How do I insert the code to do this into my JavaScript variable?  I'm new to this, Thanks!!

Comment: You might want to start here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Unfortunately questions about [coding](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here. You might ask this over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), but be sure to include enough details and any code you've tried, as they generally like to see some attempt at coding first.

Answer (score 1):

It seams like the best way to go about it, is to have a php file which returns the output of your data set; and just make a ajax call to it. Maybe these resources will help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288709/load-javascript-array-with-mysql-database-data
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964799/load-data-from-database-using-javascript
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530682/load-info-from-a-db-into-a-javascript-game